# How to yum install always answering yes in the y/n questions

Tags: linux, centos

In Linux Centos 6-64 bits, when we install a package, it asks us to press y or n sometimes plus enter such as this: "Is it ok? [y/n]".

What should we add in the command "yum install something" so always when it would stop the installation to ask y/n it always go automatically on the "y" (yes) always, without stopping to ask?

Thanks

Comment: This could easily have been answered by googling `yum yes`

Comment: You can always pipe a response like so 'echo yes | yum install xyz'. this is more useful when a program doesn't have a yes flag

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers when there's a possibility for multiple prompts, you can use `yes | yum ...`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### How do I run `yum install` and always answer `yes`?

Use the `-y` or `--assumeyes` command line option:

```
-y, --assumeyes
    Assume yes; assume that the answer to any question which would be asked is yes.
    Configuration Option: assumeyes
```

Source [yum(8) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html)

Comment: Out of curiosity, would yum then uninstall any software that clashes with what you're trying to install, without you knowing about it?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be "yes | yum install the_package"